# nuxt 3 and loading external scripts

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am loading this script into my nuxt3 application

```
(function() {
    var theScript = document.createElement("script");    theScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    theScript.setAttribute("src", "https://clients.yomdel.com/tools/chat_script.js?url=https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(theScript);
    theScript.onerror = function(){
    }
})();
```

I this script in my a js file in my public directory `scripts/livechat.js` and loaded in via via my `nuxt.config.js`,

```
app: {
        head: {
            script: [
                {
                    src: "/scripts/livechat.js"
                }
            ],
        },
    },
```

The script loads in but throws an error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')

which is this line,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(theScript);
```

I assuming that as the first load of a nuxt application happens on the server then `document` does not exist? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an option for it to load in the client inside the `nuxt.config` file. But, you can use the plugins to load your live chat script.

`~/plugins/livechat.client.js`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin( ( nuxApp ) => {
    nuxApp.hook( 'app:mounted', () => {
        useHead( {
            script: [
                {
                    src: '/scripts/livechat.js'
                }
            ]
        } )
    } )
} )
```

Or this

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin( ( nuxApp ) => {
    useHead( {
        script: [
            {
                src: '/scripts/livechat.js'
            }
        ]
    } )
} )
```

Example inside your live chat js file.

```js
( function () {
    console.log( 'Script is running...' )
    var theScript = document.createElement( "script" ); theScript.setAttribute( "type", "text/javascript" )
    theScript.setAttribute( "src", "https://clients.yomdel.com/tools/chat_script.js?url=https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/" )
    document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ].appendChild( theScript )
    theScript.onerror = function () {
    }
} )()
```

Tested and it works.

[image]

Using the `app:mounted` hook, you can remove the `.client` prefix on the file name and it will still work.